# append to select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a select option listbox,

I want to append on button click into the listbox where, textbox1 will be value and textbox2 will be text.

Can anyone make this work? thanks.

**http://jsfiddle.net/6y54P/4/**

```
$("#listbox1").change(function() {
   var svalue = $("#listbox1 option:selected").val();
   var stext = $("#listbox1 option:selected").text();
    $("#textbox1").val(svalue);
    $("#textbox2").val(stext);
});

$("#button1").click(function(){
   var svalue = $("#textbox1").val(svalue);
   var stext = $("#textbox2").val(stext);
   $('<option value="'+ svalue +'"').html(stext).appendTo("#listbox1");
});
```

Comment: you're retrieving the values incorrectly. do it like `var foo = $('bar').val()`, with nothing in the parens for `val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#listbox1").change(function() {
   var svalue = $("#listbox1 option:selected").val();
   var stext = $("#listbox1 option:selected").text();
    $("#textbox1").val(svalue);
    $("#textbox2").val(stext);
});

$("#button1").click(function(){
   var svalue = $("#textbox1").val();
   var stext = $("#textbox2").val();
   $('<option value="'+ svalue +'">'+svalue+'</option>').html(stext).appendTo("#listbox1");
});
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6y54P/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#listbox")` use `$("#listbox1")` // in jsfiddle

Inside your button handler you need to fetch the values again

```
var svalue = $("#listbox1 option:selected").val();
var stext = $("#listbox1 option:selected").text();
```